# Adding column to table in a for loop

Tags: r

I'm running the following code on quite large data frames. I've rewritten it for the iris dataset to make it reproducable.
I'm quite unexperienced with the `apply` functions and I find them a pain in the bum to apply them.

**Is there any ways to drastically improve the performance of this process?**

```
lmfit <- lm(iris$Petal.Width ~ iris$Sepal.Length + iris$Sepal.Width)
out_index <- 1
TableWithResiduals <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = ncol(iris) +1, nrow = nrow(iris)))
for (row in 1:length(resid(lmfit))){
  TableWithResiduals[out_index,] <- cbind(iris[row,],resid(lmfit)[row])
  out_index <- out_index +1  
}
colnames(TableWithResiduals) <- colnames(iris)
colnames(TableWithResiduals)[length(TableWithResiduals)] <- "Residual_value"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the doc for `cbind`, which you already use, you will see that it can take whole matrices, data.frames, and vectors as inputs. This means you can just do:

```
TableWithResiduals <- cbind(iris, Residual_value = resid(lmfit))
```

You could also have done:

```
TableWithResiduals <- iris
TableWithResiduals$Residual_value <- resid(lmfit)
```

If it were not for these solutions, there are a few things that could be improved in your code. First, you could have used `row` directly instead of the `out_index` variable you created. Second, the last two lines of your code could have been merged into one: `names(TableWithResiduals) <- c(names(iris), "Residual_value")`. Also, if you look at the doc for `lm`, you could have saved yourself some typing by doing `lm(Petal.Width ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width, iris)`

Comment: Thanks alot! Using the `TableWithResiduals$Residual_value <- resid(lmfit)` the improvement in speed is almost a thousand times according to microbenchmark, it's almost instantaneously now :)